# Why does ";" == ";" evaluates to "false"?

Tags: javascript, firebug, conditional-statements, equals, equality

Why does this (Firebug Console):

```
> ";" == ";"
> false
```

But this:

```
> ';' == ';'
> true
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: compare both `";".charCodeAt(0)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/14147/

Comment: @P.JAYASRI  — What's the point of that link? It doesn't have the same code as the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, despite looking similar, U+037E : [GREEK QUESTION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/037e/index.htm) is not the same as U+003B : [SEMICOLON](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b/index.htm)

[What Unicode character is this?](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) to the rescue for this kind of trick question.

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin said. Those characters aren't the same. The semicolons in the first example aren't both semicolons. Don't copy and paste, try to write it yourself and you'll see, there is no difference and they'll both return true. HOWGH

Answer (score -1):

Because

; is an English keyboard language set

And ; is a Greek keyboard language imput.

So the program is identifying two different languages, and seeing them a false , because they aren't the same keyboard format.

So please make sure to use the same keyboard for all your programming efforts